# How to validate one attribute Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that gets a users name.

If this name is valid then I send them to another form to enter in their email, password etc.

I want to validate the name only.

Is there a way to do `@user.name.valid?`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such method. You can however write your own:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def attribute_valid?(name)
    if valid?
      true
    else
      !!self.errors[name]
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Although this basically runs all validations and later checks whether your concrete attribute was among the bad ones. So, if you are looking for performance, this is not the solution.

Comment: I was thinking then maybe just use jquery and validate on the client side.  Its just one field for a name so might be the better and easier solution especially performance wise.

Comment: I think client side validations might be a good idea (if it satisfies your security/integrity needs). The !! operator is just double the ! operator which indeed means "not not". I use it to not receive the error message when there is one but just `true`

Answer (score -1):

In case someone ends up here: [I wrote a gem for that](https://github.com/KevinBongart/valid_attribute).

```
gem 'valid_attribute', github: 'kevinbongart/valid_attribute'
```

Let's say you have:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ }
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :company }
  validates :legacy_code, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ }
end
```

This gem lets you test the validity of each attribute independentely:

```
company = Company.new
product = Product.new(company: company, name: "heyo")

# Test only one attribute:
product.valid_attribute?(:company)      # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:name)         # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:legacy_code)  # => false

# Test several attributes at once, like a boss:
product.valid_attribute?(:company, :name)               # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:company, :name, :legacy_code) # => false

# Wow, you can even filter down to a specific validator:
product.valid_attribute?(name: :format)                     # => true
product.valid_attribute?(name: [:format, :uniqueness])      # => true
product.valid_attribute?(name: :format, company: :presence) # => true
```

Comment: It is better to provide the steps here, and use the link as a reference for further details. That way your answer does not lose all of the value it might have, once the link becomes invalid.